# Disabling the linux virtual console completely

Tags: linux-kernel, raspberry-pi

I have a raspberry pi, which listens on the network and plays videos on hdmi when told.
This is accomplished with omxplayer, without X11.

I want to make the screen completely back at all times except when omxplayer is showing something. By default there were a getty, linux debug output, a blinking cursor, a raspberry logo etc showing on the hdmi output. I have managed to disable everything with several cmdline.txt options.

However, it feels like a whole bunch of workarounds. I would like to disable the text output to the screen altogether in linux, like disabling the virtual terminal and the console altogether. Just like there is nothing on the 3.5mm sound output by default I don't want anything on the hdmi. Is this possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to recompile the kernel.

After enabling CONFIG_EXPERT, you can disable CONFIG_VT.

Comment: So there is no cmdline option like vt.disable?

Comment: [No](http://git.kernel.org/cgit/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/tree/Documentation/kernel-parameters.txt).

Answer (score 0):

Check out [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47822883/how-to-disable-a-virtual-terminal-in-yocto-linux) question for details on how to disable the VT console.

For my specific system (i.MX6), getty was still being initialized on tty1 so I had to disable it on startup:

```
systemctl stop getty@tty1.service
systemctl disable getty@tty1.service
```

You can also disable the framebuffer through a bootloader option. I'm not sure which bootloader the RPi uses but you can look into the `fbcon` parameter.

The default might be `fbcon=map:1` in which case you should to map it to a different fbdev device. This should remove the VT console entirely.