# How to disable a Virtual Terminal in Yocto Linux

Tags: linux, terminal, console, yocto, systemd

Would anyone know how to disable the virtual terminals in linux?  I am using Yocto, Morty version on an i.MX6 processor.  Even though our base distribution is Yocto, unfortunately we have diverged from building it with recipes, so this is more of a straight linux question than Yocto…

To give some detail as to my problem:  It is for an embedded device that has an HDMI port - when I attach a terminal to the HDMI port it shows the Linux Penguin logo, a getty service and blanks out after 600 seconds.  I just want to use the hdmi port as an output with nothing displayed on the output and I want it to stay on all the time.

I have found that the hdmi port maps to /dev/tty1 – when I type:  echo “asdfasdf” > /dev/tty1 I see the characters output to the monitor.

Here are a few things I have tried to no avail – a lot of these are not needed if I can figure out how to disable it as a virtual terminal…

•   I figured out how to disable the getty service but a cursor still blinks.   I don’t even want a cursor to show

•   I have tried to disable the display of the penguins by disabling the LOGO in the kernel config parameters - I commented anything with LOGO out:

```
CONFIG_LOGO=y
CONFIG_LOGO_LINUX_MONO=y
CONFIG_LOGO_LINUX_VGA16=y
CONFIG_LOGO_LINUX_CLUT224=y
```

To no avail.  The logo still shows : .

•   The fact that it blanks after 600 seconds is console blanking – I can see it set to 600 in the file:  /sys/module/kernel/parameters/consoleblank.  When I issue the command:  echo -e '\033[9;0]'>/dev/tty1
It sets the console blanking to 0 and wakes the terminal.  Being able to wake the console up is limited success but I would like to disable the virtual terminal altogether…

•   I tried commenting out any virtual terminal defines in the config file to no avail:

```
CONFIG_VT=y
CONFIG_VT_CONSOLE=y
CONFIG_VT_CONSOLE_SLEEP=y
CONFIG_HW_CONSOLE=y
CONFIG_VT_HW_CONSOLE_BINDING=y
```

Everything I have read suggests that /dev/tty1 is a virtual terminal or console.  From what I read about the VT option, disabling the CONFIG_VT should do it:

> VT — Virtual terminal Say yes here to get support for terminal devices
>   with display and keyboard devices. These are called "virtual" because
>   you can run several virtual terminals (also called virtual consoles)
>   on one physical terminal. You need at least one virtual terminal
>   device in order to make use of your keyboard and monitor. Therefore,
>   only people configuring an embedded system would want to say no here
>   in order to save some memory; the only way to log into such a system
>   is then via a serial or network connection. Virtual terminals are
>   useful because, for example, one virtual terminal can display system
>   messages and warnings, another one can be used for a text-mode user
>   session, and a third could run an X session, all in parallel.
>   Switching between virtual terminals is done with certain key
>   combinations, usually Alt-function key. If you are unsure, say yes, or
>   else you won't be able to do much with your Linux system.

But for some reason it doesn’t do anything!

•   I found this thread;  https://askubuntu.com/questions/357039/how-do-i-disable-virtual-consoles-tty1-6 among others, but none are much help since my distribution does not have any of the directories in the solutions offered in this thread or any others I have found.  For instance I do not have a /etc/events.d nor do I have a /etc/default/console-setup file nor do I have a /etc/init directory…   I imagine the reason for this is that my distribution uses systemd and the solutions are SysV based init maybe?

Disabling the logo or console blanking would not be necessary if I could just figure out how to disable that port as a terminal…

So does anyone have pointers or things I could try?  I am relatively new (returning after 10 years - I worked with DNX 10 years ago v2.6 and it seems everything I knew about init is fairly obsolete lol) to linux so I am sure I am missing a lot…

Thanks,
-   Chuck

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think I found the answer to my question.  This is actually a frame buffer console documented here:  Documentation/fb/fbcon.txt.  From the documentation:

> The framebuffer console (fbcon), as its name implies, is a text
>   console running on top of the framebuffer device. It has the
>   functionality of any standard text console driver, such as the VGA
>   console, with the added features that can be attributed to the
>   graphical nature of the framebuffer.

Commenting out the line

CONFIG_FRAMEBUFFER_CONSOLE=y

In the configuration file located in /arch/arm/configs will disable it.

Also this part of the documentation shows you how to disable it at runtime:

> So, how do we unbind fbcon from the console? Part of the answer is in
>   Documentation/console/console.txt. To summarize:
>
> Echo a value to the bind file that represents the framebuffer console
>   driver. So assuming vtcon1 represents fbcon, then:
>
> echo 1 > sys/class/vtconsole/vtcon1/bind - attach framebuffer console
>   to
>                                              console layer echo 0 > sys/class/vtconsole/vtcon1/bind - detach framebuffer console from
>                                              console layer

When I issue the echo 0 command, the cursor stops blinking and starts blinking again when I issue the echo 1 command.

I think there is another way of doing it as well by modifying the Yocto build environment by putting the USE_VT="0" in the OpenEmbedded machine config file.  The "USE_VT" variable is referenced by the sysvinit-inittab recipe.  This answer was given to me from the Yocto Linux mailing list - but I have not tested it since we have diverged from Yocto...